# Firefox disable browser zoom but allow element zoom on pinch

Tags: firefox, d3.js, zooming, pinch

I've got a site running aimed at touchscreens running Firefox (very specific I know, but it will hopefully help with a solution)
On the page in question, I've got a d3 map that I'm trying to enable pinch zooming for, however any pinch gesture is causing Firefox to set the zoom for the whole page. Is there a way to prevent the page zooming and only allow the map to zoom?

It's not an issue if I have to modify Firefox config settings but I'd prefer to avoid it and rely entirely on javascript if possible.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this using the [viewport metatag](https://www.google.com.cy/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=viewport%20meta%20tag%20user-scalable) and [Hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

This will disable the default browser zoom.

---

You can then use [Hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/) to capture gesture events which you will then pass to your D3.js code to zoom your map

Comment: sadly it seems to me, that most browsers ignore the "user-scalable=no". Are there any new insights, how Chrome (where it works to pinch-zoom a svg without browser zoom) handles this? Even on hammerjs's website, its not possible to pinch-zoom the example in FF