# google map pinch not working on touchscreen tv

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, multi-touch, zooming, pinchzoom

I have embeded google maps using `google-maps-api v3`on my site. i am trying to use a touchscreen tv to zoom in and out of the map, however it keeps resizing the browser window instead. i am using firefox.

http://www.spectrumgeo.com/mcmap/large.php

the following code prevents zooming using keyboard `ctrl (-/+)`

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
            if (event.ctrlKey==true && (event.which == '107' || event.which == '109')) {
                alert('disabling zooming ! ');
                event.preventDefault();
             }
        });
```

I have tried hammer as mnentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850902/firefox-disable-browser-zoom-but-allow-element-zoom-on-pinch) but does not work.

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('googlemap');

        var mc = new Hammer.Manager(myElement);

        // create a pinch and rotate recognizer
        // these require 2 pointers
        var pinch = new Hammer.Pinch();
        var rotate = new Hammer.Rotate();

        // we want to detect both the same time
        pinch.recognizeWith(rotate);

        // add to the Manager
        mc.add([pinch, rotate]);

        mc.on("panleft panright tap press", function(ev) {
            //myElement.textContent = ev.type +" gesture detected.";
            alert(ev.type +" ");
        });

        mc.on("pinch rotate", function(ev) {
            //myElement.textContent += ev.type +" ";
            alert(ev.type +" ");
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing lot of research and reading lot of blogs This can be achieved by spoofing User Agent or Setting Navigator's msMaxTouchPoints Property. This is inspired by the solution from Brian (https://github.com/bamnet/map_sandbox/tree/master/forceTouchUI ) where he is spoofing the User Agent. 
I have modified little bit to make it work by setting navigator.msMaxTouchPoints property as shown in JsFiddle Example

This what we have ended up doing

```js
function EnableTouchUI(){
  // Check if the browser supports touch events
  if('ontouchstart' in window || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch) {
     navigator = navigator || {};
 navigator.msMaxTouchPoints = navigator.msMaxTouchPoints || 2;
  }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 EnableTouchUI();
});
```

Check out the working example here 
https://jsfiddle.net/abidCharlotte49er/qLn8hkv0/

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#DefaultControls), only mobile device would have touch control. It seems like there are no setting to enable it. However, you can set your user-agent to android tablet to enable it.

Comment: how can i set the user agent?

Comment: using plug-in like this https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/user-agent-overrider/

Comment: windows 8 seems to very well and much better than previous windows with touch compatibility.

Comment: I would think so too. Since windows 8 is decided for tablet... I think if you launch the browser under the modern UI (full screen) mode, google maps would give you a touch interface