# d3 zoom: prevent page zoom when using a touchscreen

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, zooming, touchscreen

Pretty much a newbie here to javascript and not a 'full-fledged' developer, so be gentle! : )

I'm creating a zoomable map with d3 (using v3 at the moment), and I want to be able to view this map in both touchscreen and non-touchscreen device browsers (i.e., mobile and pc).  On touchscreens, when using the pinch gesture on the map svg element to which I've applied the zoom, the entire page zooms instead of just the map.  You can see the same behavior on many of the d3 examples (e.g., https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708).  Do I need to prevent default behaviors/write custom handling for the touchstart event?  Since such a large percentage of devices out there are touchscreens, I'd imagine that d3 has dealt with this, and I've missed the documentation/StackOverflow threads on it?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found that this question was already answered (after what I thought was sufficiently thorough searching for such an answer :) ).  Perhaps others will be searching with the same terms I did and this post will help direct them to the answer.

[Firefox disable browser zoom but allow element zoom on pinch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29850902/5738654)

Comment: please do not share a link here.  After some days the link may be broken or not available.

Comment: @VedPrakash I think it's acceptable to put links.  If not, could you point me to where it says this on Stack Overflow?  But I should've put the Stack Overflow permalink--I've updated the URL.

Comment: That does not mean a link is bad. That merely means link-only is bad. It's best to have both link and context, isn't it? Please see this [help center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - "Links to external resources are encouraged".